# How do you install PyLucene on OpenSuSE or another rpm based distro?

Tags: linux, lucene, rpm, opensuse, pylucene

I'm trying to install pylucene on opensuse; is there an rpm package in the repositories, or a repository I could add? On Ubunty this would be:
sudo apt-get install pylucene

I don't have any experience with rpm based distros, so a basic level explanation would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there few rpm packages, but they are very old, so I will recommend you to install it manually with help of official guides:

http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/install.html (mind Download button near the top left corner)